# Multi-dimensional gaussian integral with non-symmetric & non-hermitian coefficient matrix

Tags: gaussian-integral

There is a commonly used formula in quantum field theory,
\begin{equation}
\int\prod_{i} \frac{dz_{i}^{\dagger} dz_{i}}{2\pi} e^{-z^{\dagger}Az}=\frac{1}{\det(A)}, (1)
\end{equation}
where $z=x+\text{i}y$ is a complex vector, and $A$ is a matrix with positive definite hermitian part (We know a matrix can always be written as sumation of hermitian part and anti-hermitian part, $A=\frac{A+A^{\dagger}}{2}+\frac{A-A^{\dagger}}{2}$).
The difficulty is coefficient matrix $A$ is **neither hermitian nor complex symmetric**.

**For hermitian matrix $A$**, Eq (1) is easy to verify, because a hermitian matrix can be diagonalized by a unitary matrix.

**For complex symmetric $A$**, the problem is a little bit more tougher although there are no less than two ways to manage.

1. The first way is analytical continuation from a real symmetric
   matrix. For real symmetric matrix A,

   \begin{equation} z^{\dagger}A z=[x^{T},y^{T}] \begin{bmatrix} A &   
   \\   &  A \\ \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}   x \\   y \\
   \end{bmatrix}, \end{equation}

   the integral is
   $\sqrt{\det(A)}^{-1}\times\sqrt{\det(A)}^{-1}=\det(A)^{-1}$.

   If the imaginary part emerges, $A\rightarrow A+iB$, where $B$ is
   also a real symmetric matrix. The positive definiteness of the
   original real symmetric $A$ guarantees that there exists a finite
   range on the real axis, i.e., $\epsilon\in[-\alpha,\alpha]$, in
   which the matrix $A+\epsilon B$ is still positive definite so that
   the integral remains $\det(A)^{-1}$.

   When the $\epsilon$ becomes complex number the real part of which is in
   the range, $\text{Re}({\epsilon})\in[-\alpha,\alpha]$, while the
   imaginary part is arbitary, the integral always converges and the
   determinant is not going to touch zero in the range, so the quantities on
   both sides of Eq (1) exist. According to the mathematical theorem
   (equal on piece, equal all over) for analytical functions, when $\epsilon = 0+\text{i}$, the equation
   still holds, so for complex symmetric $A$ with positive definite real part, Eq (1) is verified. Here we noticed that the original statement is A is a matix with positive definite hermitian part. For complex symmetric matrix, the hermitian part, $\frac{A+A^{\dagger}}{2}$ is the real part and the anti-hermitian part, $\frac{A-A^{\dagger}}{2}$ is the imaginary part.
2. The second way is based on the fact that if the real part of a complex symmetric matrix is positive definite, it can be diagonalized simultaneously with the imaginary part. There is a good description in section 3 and 4 from David K. zhang's note, [enter link description here](http://david-k-zhang.com/notes/gaussian-integrals.html).

**I can not figure out the proof for a general complex matrix with positive definite hermitian part.**

**Looking forward to your reply.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think decomposing $A$ is a good idea. Here's a simple [proof](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/13aa/494c312d57a92d72e408bc4f3503edaac8eb.pdf)  for non symmetric matrix. Not sure if it can give you some hint.

Comment: This is a comment and not an answer. You can leave comments once you have 15 rep.